# How to check uri status in next task to excute

Tags: ansible

Hi I am using rest api post request to create one resource thru URI module in ansible... I want to check the status of the resource created or not in next task to execute it..can you please suggest me how can I do this.. here resource is new server I am creating and want to install packages 
In next tasks when it is spin up and on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `failed_when: false` the playbook execution will not fail on error codes. Then you can register the result and access the status code using the `status` key (follows an example.yml):

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Example uri module status
    uri:
      url: http://www.example.com
      return_content: no
    register: result
    failed_when: false

  - debug:
      var: result.status
```

Comment: How can I get the response of Post method addition to the status...like I need ouput of the request which I sent

Comment: You'll have to add return_content: yes